# Running code on top of camera feed on Android in actionscript 3?

Tags: android, actionscript, camera

I´m trying to run some code on mouseclick over an camera feed on android.
It´s working fine on iOS but when i´m doing it on Android the image gets distorted and divided in to four pictures.
Anyone have had this problem?
Know of any solution?
Best Måns